# Python context manager: conditionally executing body?

Tags: python, contextmanager

I'm writing an MPI-based application (but MPI doesn't matter in my question, I mention it only to expose the rationale) and in some cases, when there is less work items than processes, I need to create a new communicator excluding the processes that have nothing to do. Finally, the new communicator has to be freed by the processes that have work to do (and only by them).

A neat way to do that would be to write:

```
with filter_comm(comm, nworkitems) as newcomm:
    ... do work with communicator newcomm...
```

the body being executed only by the processes that have work to do.

Is there a way in a context manager to avoid executing the body?
I understand that context managers have rightfully been designed to avoid hiding control flows, but I wonder if it is possible to circumvent that, since in my case I think it would be justified for clarity sake.

Comment: if you'd throw an exception in `__init__()` or `__enter__()` it might skip the body ...

Comment: @moooeeep: Yeah, but it would... throw an excepion instead.

Comment: @NiklasB. every approach has its pros and cons! Using an explicit `if` condition is probably the [more pythonic way](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) ... Indeed.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The ability to conditionally skip context manager body has been proposed but rejected as documented in [PEP 377](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0377/).

I did some research about alternatives. Here are my findings.

First let me explain the background of my code examples. You have a bunch of devices you want to work with. For every device you have to acquire the driver for the device; then work with the device using the driver; and lastly release the driver so others can acquire the driver and work with the device.

Nothing out of the ordinary here. The code looks roughly like this:

```
driver = getdriver(devicename)
try:
  dowork(driver)
finally:
  releasedriver(driver)
```

But once every full moon when the planets are not aligned correctly the acquired driver for a device is bad and no work can be done with the device. This is no big deal. Just skip the device this round and try again next round. Usually the driver is good then. But even a bad driver needs to be released otherwise no new driver can be acquired.

(the firmware is proprietary and the vendor is reluctant to fix or even acknowledge this bug)

The code now looks like this:

```
driver = getdriver(devicename)
try:
  if isgooddriver(driver):
    dowork(driver)
  else:
    handledrivererror(geterrordetails(driver))
finally:
  release(driver)
```

That is a lot of boilerplate code that needs to be repeated everytime work needs to be done with a device. A prime candidate for python's [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) also known as [with statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement). It might look like this:

```
# note: this code example does not work
@contextlib.contextmanager
def contextgetdriver(devicename):
  driver = getdriver(devicename)
  try:
    if isgooddriver(driver):
      yield driver
    else:
      handledrivererror(geterrordetails(driver))
  finally:
    release(driver)
```

And then the code when working with a device is short and sweet:

```
with contextgetdriver(devicename) as driver:
  dowork(driver)
```

But this does not work. Because a context manager has to yield. It may not not yield. Not yielding will result in a `RuntimeException` raised by `contextmanager`.

So we have to pull out the check from the context manager

```
# this works but you don't win much
@contextlib.contextmanager
def contextgetdriver(devicename):
  driver = getdriver(devicename)
  try:
    yield driver
  finally:
    release(driver)
```

and put it in the body of the `with` statement

```
with contextgetdriver(devicename) as driver:
  if isgooddriver(driver):
    dowork(driver)
  else:
    handledrivererror(geterrordetails(driver))
```

This is ugly because now we again have some boilerplate that needs to be repeated everytime we want to work with a device.

So we want a context manager that can conditionaly execute the body. But we have none because [PEP 377](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0377/) (suggesting exactly this feature) was rejected.

Instead of not yielding we can raise an Exception ourselves:

```
# this works but you don't win much
@contextlib.contextmanager
def contextgetdriver(devicename):
  driver = getdriver(devicename)
  try:
    if isgooddriver(driver):
      yield driver
    else:
      raise NoGoodDriverException(geterrordetails(driver))
  finally:
    release(driver)
```

but now you need to handle the exception:

```
try:
  with contextgetdriver(devicename) as driver:
    dowork(driver)
except NoGoodDriverException as e:
  handledrivererror(e.errordetails)
```

which has practically the same cost of code complexity as the explicit testing for good driver.

Side note: with an exception we can decide to not handle it here and instead let it bubble up the call stack and handle it elsewhere. also there is a difference: by the time we handle the exception the driver has already been released. While with the explicit check the driver has not been released. (the except is outside of the with statement while the else is inside the with statement)

Now to the alternatives

I found that abusing a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator) works quite well as a replacement of a context manager which can skip the body

```
# this works but please don't
def generatorgetdriver(devicename):
  driver = getdriver(devicename)
  try:
    if isgooddriver(driver):
      yield driver
    else:
      handledrivererror(geterrordetails(driver))
  finally:
    release(driver)
```

But then the calling code looks very much like a loop

```
for driver in generatorgetdriver(devicename):
  dowork(driver)
```

If you can live with this (please don't) then you have a context manager that can conditionaly execute the body.

It seems that the only way to prevent the boilerplate code is with a callback

```
# this works fine but it is no longer a context manager really
def workwithdevice(devicename, callback):
  driver = getdriver(devicename)
  try:
    if isgooddriver(driver):
      callback(driver)
    else:
      handledrivererror(geterrordetails(driver))
  finally:
    release(driver)
```

And the calling code

```
workwithdevice(devicename, dowork)
```

Comment: Kudos for the effort that went into this answer. Was very helpful.

Comment: I like the generator idea. I wonder, however, how I would implement a cache with it, because the loop body is skipped if the generator does *not* return anything. I'd need it the other way round: ideally, I would do: `for values in get_from_cheap_cache(): values=expensive_function()` and then access `values` after the loop. With the generator solution, `values` is either assigned twice or not at all...

Comment: @lesmana I have often seen the flow that you have here, where the **core call** is actually before the `try` statement.  For instance, you have `driver, isgood = getdriver(devicename)` and then the `try` on the next statement.  Why is this?  I do not understand why the entire thing isn't in the `try` statement.  What if the `driver, isgood = getdriver(devicename)` code is the code that actually fails?  Then the `finally` clause is skipped, right?  Why would we want that?

Comment: my code examples assume that `getdriver` never fails. the `finally` is to ensure that driver is released even if `dowork` fails. of course in real world `getdriver` can and will fail. but consider this: if `getdriver` fails there would be no driver returned. so the `release` will itself fail because driver is not defined. that means to handle error from `getdriver` you need yet another `try` surrounding the entire thing.

Answer (score 7):

This functionality seems to have been [rejected](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0377/). Python developers often prefer the explicit variant:

```
if need_more_workers():
    newcomm = get_new_comm(comm)
    # ...
```

You can also use higher-order functions:

```
def filter_comm(comm, nworkitems, callback):
    if foo:
        callback(get_new_comm())

# ...

some_local_var = 5
def do_work_with_newcomm(newcomm):
    # we can access the local scope here

filter_comm(comm, nworkitems, do_work_with_newcomm)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I've written to the python-dev mailing list.

Comment: I realize that saying "No" is an important part to keeping a product clean and simple, but often I feel like Guido says it just a bit too often. IE, no pattern matching, no range literals, and now no conditionals for context managers.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this instead:

```
@filter_comm(comm, nworkitems)
def _(newcomm):  # Name is unimportant - we'll never reference this by name.
    ... do work with communicator newcomm...
```

You implement the `filter_comm` decorator to do whatever work it should with `comm` and `nworkitems`, then based on those results decide whether to execute the function it's wrapped around or not, passing in `newcomm`.

It's not quite as elegant as `with`, but I think this is a bit more readable and closer to what you want than the other proposals. You could name the inner function something other than `_` if you don't like that name, but I went with it since it's the normal name used in Python when the grammar requires a name which you'll never actually use.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar situation and I solved it with help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23665658). I'll use the example of a "task" whose body should only be executed if the task is not "done", and which should be marked as "done" when the body finishes successfully.

The idea is that we can conditionally raise a custom exception in the body of the `with`, and then catch it in `__exit__()`. If it's our custom exception, our `__exit__()` will return `True`, which tells Python to not to bubble the exception, and if there's no exception, we can do whatever we want to do on successful completion of the body. (See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__exit__).)

```py
class Task:
    class Done(Exception):
        pass

    # interact with some external system perhaps
    def is_done(self) -> bool:
        ... 
    def mark_done(self):
        ...

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        if exc_type == self.Done:
            return True # suppress the "exception"
        if exc_type is not None:
            return False # bubble the exception

        self.mark_done() # or do whatever you want with a successful context exit
```

You can then use it like this:

```py
with Task() as my_task:
    if my_task.is_done():
        raise my_task.Done

    do_work()
    ... # etc
```

You could even factor out the conditional to something like:

```py
class Task:
    ...
    def check_done(self):
        if self.is_done():
            raise self.Done
    ...
```

Then:

```py
with Task() as task:
    task.check_done()

    do_work()
    ... # etc
```

IMO this solution is cleaner than the other solutions, since it doesn't involve any callbacks and your `with` body can stay at just one indentation level.