# Break or exit out of "with" statement?

Tags: python, with-statement

I'd just like to exit out of a `with` statement under certain conditions:

```
with open(path) as f:
    print 'before condition'
    if <condition>: break #syntax error!
    print 'after condition'
```

Of course, the above doesn't work. Is there a way to do this? (I know that I can invert the condition: `if not <condition>: print 'after condition'` -- any way that is like above?)

Comment: I'm curious why `if not <condition>` is undesirable in your situation.

Comment: @senderle I think having to indent the rest of the block can reduce readability and obscure the flow (especially in cases like this one where breaking out feels like the exception). Imagine three more conditions, with code blocks after each one...

Comment: Forget it... none of the answers here are worth the trouble LOL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question was asked before Python 3.4 existed but with 3.4 you can use `contextlib.supress`,
suppressing your own personal exception.

See that this (runnable as is) code

```py
from contextlib import suppress

class InterruptWithBlock(UserWarning):
    """To be used to interrupt the march of a with"""

condition = True
with suppress(InterruptWithBlock):
    print('before condition')
    if condition: raise InterruptWithBlock()
    print('after condition')

# Will not print 'after condition` if condition is True.
```

So with the code in the question, you'd do:

```py
with suppress(InterruptWithBlock) as _, open(path) as f:
    print('before condition')
    if <condition>: raise InterruptWithBlock()
    print('after condition')
```

Note: If you're (still) before 3.4, you can still make your own `suppress` context manager easily.

Comment: Amazing. I updated this to be the accepted answer, as python >= 3.4 is now widely the norm.

Answer (score 96):

`with` giving you trouble? Throw more `with`-able objects at the problem!

```
class fragile(object):
    class Break(Exception):
      """Break out of the with statement"""

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.value.__enter__()

    def __exit__(self, etype, value, traceback):
        error = self.value.__exit__(etype, value, traceback)
        if etype == self.Break:
            return True
        return error
```

Just wrap the expression you're going to `with` with `fragile`, and `raise fragile.Break` to break out at any point!

```
with fragile(open(path)) as f:
    print 'before condition'
    if condition:
        raise fragile.Break
    print 'after condition'
```

#### Benefits of this setup

- Uses `with` and just the `with`; doesn't wrap your function in a semantically misleading one-run 'loop' or a narrowly specialized function, and doesn't force you to do any extra error handling after the `with`.
- Keeps your local variables available, instead of having to pass them to a wrapping function.
- Nestable!

  ```
  with fragile(open(path1)) as f:
      with fragile(open(path2)) as g:
          print f.read()
          print g.read()
          raise fragile.Break
          print "This wont happen"
      print "This will though!"
  ```

  This way, you don't have to create a new function to wrap the outer `with` if you want both to break.
- Doesn't require restructuring at all: just wrap what you already have with `fragile` and you're good to go!

#### Downsides of this setup

- Doesn't actually use a 'break' statement. Can't win em all ;)

Comment: I think this is a better setup than most others. Doesn't require refactoring of the code, and `fragile()` is reusable.

Comment: Just came back by this, and I do like this.

Comment: I think a larger downside is that it makes it a bit clumsy to call the methods of the context manager that you have wrapped. I like the general solution but would instead implement it as a static function which monkey patches the __enter__ and __exit__ by wrapping the currently existing __enter__ and __exit__. There is probably some fancy way to do that with a decorator aswell....

Comment: It's clever and uses the decorator pattern (my favorite), but it uses exception handling for control flow. I'm on the fence.

Comment: This is a clever idea which I'm adapting to allow me to still use Context Managers while conditionally skipping cleanup of a `with`'d resource (a temporary file) if an exception occurred during processing, permitting debugging.

Comment: If a  `Break1` subclass is added to `fragile` and the `fragile.__exit__` method is modified to raise a `Break` exception if called with `Break1`,  then breaking out of both of two nested `with`s  is implemented.

Comment: Is a 'pass' statement missing inside class Break or maybe I'm mistaken?

Comment: @madtyn the docstring counts as a statement, so we're able to omit the `pass`. Keeping or omitting the `pass` in this case is a matter of preference.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this detail and I would never have immagined this.

Answer (score 58):

The best way would be to encapsulate it in a function and use `return`:

```
def do_it():
    with open(path) as f:
        print 'before condition'
        if <condition>:
            return
        print 'after condition'
```

Comment: This returns but doesn't quite "break out" of a with statement. Users must be aware that the `__exit__` is executed regardless with this approach.

Answer (score 22):

This is an ancient question, but this is an application for the handy "breakable scope" idiom.  Just imbed your `with` statement inside:

```
for _ in (True,):
    with open(path) as f:
        print 'before condition'
        if <condition>: break
        print 'after condition'
```

This idiom creates a "loop", always executed exactly once, for the sole purpose of enclosing a block of code inside a scope that can be broken out of conditionally.  In OP's case, it was a context manager invocation to be enclosed, but it could be any bounded sequence of statements that may require conditional escape.

The accepted answer is fine, but this technique does the same thing without needing to create a function, which is not always convenient or desired.

Comment: I like that this clearly only executes once (rather than the `while True` variants), and that you included a name for the idiom.

Answer (score 12):

I think you should just restructure the logic:

```
with open(path) as f:
    print 'before condition checked'
    if not <condition>:
        print 'after condition checked'
```

Comment: @jmilloy, I think this is at least as good a solution as encapsulating the `with` statement in a function and using `return`, or raising an exception. Frankly, under many circumstances, I think this would be the most elegant and readable solution.

Comment: @senderle Agreed 100%. However, it's simply not the question.

Comment: Well, I guess if we're discussing hypothetical poor constructs that Python doesn't allow, we could bemoan the lack of a decent goto statement :-)

http://entrian.com/goto/

Answer (score 8):

Since `break` can only occur inside a loop your options are somewhat limited inside the `with` to:

- return (put "with" + associated statements inside function)
- exit   (bail from program - probably not ideal)
- exception (generate exception inside "with", catch below)

Having a function and using `return` is probably the cleanest and easiest solution here if you can isolate the `with` and the associated statements (and nothing else) inside a function.

Otherwise generate an exception inside the `with` when needed, catch immediately below/outside the `with` to continue the rest of the code.

*Update*: As OP suggests in the comments below (perhaps tonuge in cheek?) one could also wrap the `with` statement inside a loop to get the `break` to work - though that would be semantically misleading. So while a working solution, probably not something that would be recommend).

Comment: Yes I know; I'd like to know if there's something that *does* work.

Comment: @Matthias Yeah I thought of that -- seems like wrapping it in a function is a bit cleaner.

Comment: @Levon I actually tried with a `return` to check, but you can only return from a function block, not a with block. I'm sure you know this, but the way you wrote it makes it sound like returning only stops execution of the rest of the block in the `with`, whereas in reality it also prevents any code after the `with` block but in the same function.

Comment: @Matthias In fact, I often find myself wishing that `with` blocks were like `try` blocks and could be cleanly followed by exception cases. That's what I'd do if I could.

Comment: @Levon I guess we could add an option to your list: wrap the with inside a silly for loop like `for i in [0]` so that you can break.

Comment: @jmilloy I guess that's true .. in which case I would use `while True:` as the construct. It would be misleading semantically though for others looking at the code later. I think the `return` inside the function (if the with+statements work that way), followed by the exception are the best options.

Answer (score 3):

```
f = open("somefile","r")
for line in f.readlines():
       if somecondition: break;
f.close()
```

I dont think you can break out of the with... you need to use a loop...

[edit] or just do the function method others mentioned

Comment: The simpler is the better :)

Answer (score 2):

as shorthand snippet:

```
class a:
    def __enter__(self):
        print 'enter'
    def __exit__(self ,type, value, traceback):
        print 'exit'

for i in [1]:
    with a():
        print("before")
        break
        print("after")
```

...

```
enter
before
exit
```

Comment: This is reminiscent of how Python C API puts the contents of macros in a dowhile loop sometimes, except that is to get the semicolon at the end.

Comment: Is it more efficient to actually use a tuple (as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/43795918 above) or a list (as here)?

Answer (score 1):

There exists a function `__exit__()` for this purpose. Syntax is as follows:

```
with VAR = EXPR:
  try:
    BLOCK
  finally:
    VAR.__exit__()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `while True`:

```py
while True:
    with open(path) as f:
        print 'before condition'
        if <condition>: 
            break 
        print 'after condition n'
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put everything inside a function, and when the condition is true call a return.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of doing it using `try` and `except`, even though inverting the condition is probably more convenient.

```py
class BreakOut(Exception): pass

try:
    with open(path) as f:
        print('before condition')
        if <condition>: 
            raise BreakOut #syntax error!
        print('after condition')
except BreakOut:
    pass
```

Answer (score -1):

Change from "break" to "f.close"

```
with open(path) as f:
    print('before condition')
    if <condition>: f.close()
    print('after condition')
```

Comment: For one, it doesn't generalize. The question is about with statements in general, the file context manager is just an example.